# Load Div with html page contains frame

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to load a html page which contains 2 frame in a div through javascript.
my code for load html resources in a div is

```
 Util.importResource("my_div_id", 'docs/admin/index.html');
```

function for load resources in div.

```
Util={
importResource: function(divId, resourcePath, appender) {

    $("div#" + divId).load(resourcePath, function(resp, stat, req) {
        if(req.status <= 0 || req.status >= 400) {
            window.location.reload();
            return; 
        }
        if (typeof(appender) != "undefined" && appender != null)
        {
            resp += appender;
            $("div#" + divId).append(appender);
        }
    });
},
```

}

but that specific page is not displayed in div rest plain html pages loads fine.
my Html page looks like

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>asd</title>
</head>
<frameset cols="20%,*" style="border:0px solid #000000; background-color:#ffffff;"     frameborder="1">

    <frame name="toclist" title="content" src="toc.html" scrolling="auto"></frame>

    <frame name="bsscright" title="page" src="hr/title_page.html" scrolling="auto"></frame>

</frameset>
</html>
```

can any body help me out from this ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to append `resp + appender`.

```
....
if (typeof(appender) != "undefined" && appender != null)
    {
        resp += appender;
        $("div#" + divId).append(resp );
    }
  else{
       $("div#" + divId).append(resp );
   }
.....
```